# Apricity os linux, не запускается после установки

Tags: linux, archlinux

Есть ноут, на нем два диска, 1 ssd и на нем уже стоит Windows10, другой не ssd, он был пуст, поставил на него apricity os, ошибок никаких не было, в конце мне было предложено уйти с live режима и загрузиться заново уже под установленной системой.

Ноут перезагружается, а там, boot windows manager.

grub ставится, так как судя по папкам grub существует в папке boot.

Пробовал и автоматически и в ручную:

- создавал диск linuxswap подкачку на 6гб
- fat32 /boot/efi с флагом esp на 100 мб (система сама просила)
- ext4 на 50 гб

Подумал, может я не правильно разметил диск (хотя он сам обычно умеет), пробовал и в MBR и в GPT, в любом случае он устанавливается без ошибок, просит перезагрузиться и все, может я туплю и что-то неправильно сделал ?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в 2-х накопителях и 2-х операционках. Тут поможет в биосе компа шаманаство с приоритетом загрузки внутри жёстких дисков. В ноутбуках обычно это плоский список, а в компьютерах бывает отдельный пункт, который называется что-то типа `Hard Disk Boot Priority`.